# Android studio: Element receiver duplicated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

In my application, I would like to detect when my package is replaced and hence I have a receiver that is enabled in this way:

```
     <receiver
        android:name="com.x.y.ApplicationsReceiver"
        android:enabled="@bool/is_at_most_api_11" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <receiver
         android:name="com.x.y.ApplicationsReceiver"
         android:enabled="@bool/is_at_least_api_12" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

When importing my project from Eclipse to Android Studio, I got the following error:

```
 Element receiver#com.x.y.ApplicationsReceiver at AndroidManifest.xml duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Any idea how can I can solve this issue given hat I need to enable the receiver for different intent filters according to the Android API level?

Comment: The logcat clearly says that you have duplicate receiver in manifest file with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is occurring because adding same class two times in `AndroidManifest` for registering BroadcastReceiver for different Action.

Do it as by adding more then one Action in single `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.x.y.ApplicationsReceiver"
        android:enabled="@bool/is_at_most_api_11" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Now in `onReceive` method of `ApplicationsReceiver` class get Action from Intent and do what want to do according to API level:

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    String action=intent.getAction();
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
        // do your code here
     }else{
         // do your code here
     }
  }
```